# How can I restrict to certain user inputs?

Tags: python

I am creating a password validation module,but I don´t know how can I put certain rules for said password. The password needs at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 number

Here´s what I have coded so far:

```
def validacion_contraseña():
    flag = 1
    import re
    while (flag == 1):
        cont = 0
        pass=input("Ingresa una contraseña:")
        # r = re.match("^[a-z]*$", usser)
        for x in pass:
            cont = cont + 1
        if (cont < 8):
            print(True)
            flag = 0
        if not (re.match("[aA-zZ,0-9]",pass)):
            print("El nombre de usuario puede contener solo letras y números.")
            flag = 0
        if (flag == 1):
            print(True)
            flag = 0
```

Comment: How to insert code into your question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: Just added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `pass` as a variable - it's a python keyword (which means "do nothing")...

```
def something():
    pass
```

Next, I'd suggest counting each class (nums/upper/lower) separately and then checking if they meet requirements.

Also note that you almost always want to `import` something only once. Except in some advanced cases, all import statements should be at the very top of the file.

Finally, let's use a boolean `valid` variable to tidy up the loop condition a bit...

```
import re

def validacion_contraseña():
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        contrasena = input("Ingresa una contraseña:")
        nums = len(re.findall('[0-9]', contrasena))
        lower = len(re.findall('[a-z]', contrasena))
        upper = len(re.findall('[A-Z]', contrasena))

        if nums >= 1 and lower >= 1 and upper >= 1:
            valid = True
    print('Contraseña: {0}' + contrasena)
```

We're using `re.findall()` to find every non-overlapping match to the pattern. For a 1-character pattern, this effectively returns a list of matching characters.

We then count the number of items returned using `len()`.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain me what does re.findall do? I dont want to use something I dont understand. pls hahaha

Comment: `re` is a regular expression, `.findall` returns a list/enumerable of all matches it found. You can see the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall